# How to get Receiver details from Call Queue (Asterisk Dialplan) using AGI?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, asterisk, agi

I have configured one Dialplan for Incoming context.

I have following in **/etc/asterisk/extensions.conf**

```
[incoming]
switch => Realtime

exten => _X.,1,NoOp(Incoming Call Received)
exten => _X.,n,Festival(Welcome to Asterisk)
exten => _X.,n,Answer()

;call-answer.php will be called when Member Connected to Queue
exten => _X.,n,Queue(my_queue,t,,,1000,call-answer.php)
exten => _X.,n,Hangup()
```

I would like to get Caller Information who has ANSWERED Queue and get Called Queue Member information like extension id etc....

**call-answer.php**

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
set_time_limit(60);
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

require_once ('phpagi.php');
$agi = new AGI();
$agi->verbose("AGI Started after ANSWERED QUEUE",3);
$src_extension = $agi->request['agi_callerid'];
$dst_extension = $agi->request['agi_extension'];

// I want to get CALL ANSWERED QUEUE MEMBER EXTENSION NUMBER HERE.

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one line have error(no priority)

```
exten => _X.,Festival(Welcome to Asterisk)
```

You can get info about who answered in QueueLog, no need agi for that.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+log+queue_log

Also function CHANNEL(name) for sure will show you agent in macro or other side(caller). If it return caller channel, you can get other channel by reading variable BRIDGEDPEER.

You can get list of all variables in channel by issue

```
$agi->exec("Dumpchan","");
```

Comment: Updated comma in Festival with 
`exten => _X.,n,Festival(Welcome to Asterisk)`

Comment: Also, May I get CDR data after Hangup using AGI or Macro for current Call?

Comment: You can do AGI on h-extension,yes. however it is not recommended. CDR will be in database if configured. Use that data.

Comment: Actually, I am calling my AGI Script on h-extension but I could not get CDR(end) time, But other data will be coming. can you suggest me any other options. or can we have a Event for Call End using AGI Script?

Comment: There are no CDR(end) variable. Check docs again. I already suggested you correct option - use database cdrs.

Comment: I used this variable, `${CDR(end)}` = time when the call got hung up
Reff. link for All variables: `http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Detailed+Variable+List`

Comment: There are no end variable. That one is autocalculated after end of call. Sorry, no other answer.